# webpage (django) <-> midi event (alsa) in Linux

Tags: linux, webserver, midi

I would like to create a web application that sends and receives ALSA MIDI messages on Linux.  Only one web client is intended.

What kind of architecture / programs do I need for that?

I am familiar with django but can't find the missing link to ALSA (or any system with a gateway to ALSA on my Ubuntu machine).  Also, I have the small program ttymidi (http://www.varal.org/ttymidi/), that sends messages from a serial port to ALSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing what you want without any third-party library is to use [pyALSA](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-python.git;a=summary), which is the official python wrapper around the C ALSA library.

I recommend you dealing with the Sequencer API instead of the RawMIDI stuff, which is lower-level. Check out some of the [test apps](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-python.git;a=tree;f=test) and the [C API documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/), it will definetely help you to write your code.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use Python's [miscellaneous operating system interfaces](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html), but web applications aren't often designed in this way.  You may also have to worry about latency and buffering in your program.